# How can I boot rails server on windows system start?

Tags: windows, windows-task-scheduler

I have a rails app all set on windows 7 machine. I am able to run rails server by running `.bat` file (run_rails.bat) which contains the following -

`cd C:\Sites\myapp
@call rails s -e production -p 3000`

I would like to automatically start the rails app when windows OS boots. For which I tried to create a scheduled task using `schtasks.exe` - 

`schtasks /create /tn my_task /tr "C:\Scheduled Jobs\run_rails.bat" /sc onstart`

But when I reboot the system the automated task run fails with message `there are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request` however manually running the task by clicking on `run` button runs the app fine.

Are there any alternative ways to achieve this, is my approach correct to run the rails app locally ?

Answer (score 1):

The simpler way is to create a batch file with the instruction what you give in the command prompt like

```
d:

cd projects\myapp

ruby script\server
```

and then drop a copy of the file to Windows Start -> All Programs -> start up folder.

Comment: Do I have to do this manually ? Is there a way to do it via command line, so that I can put this in a script.

Comment: This starts the batch file whenever a user logs in, not on system start.

Answer (score 1):

Add an entry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`. Obviously, admin rights are needed for this.